# Wireless TDM in PIC microncontroller, using C or assembly to control time skew?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller, pic, synchronous

I'm writing a program for multiple (hundreds) PICs to talk to a main PIC in time division multiple access via RFM12B wireless module.
The main PIC send a sync packet and then each PIC should respond in its own timeslot.
All PICs are supposed to report status in one second.

The main PIC does other communication to a PC via serial port.
The question is how to control the main PIC not to skew time due to other operations delays?
I thought of using assembly instead of C so I can count the instructions and make delays.

I thought of even doing delay loops to compensate for instructions that have been skipped due to "if" statements.

This will be painful, is there a better way of doing this synchronous application? Preferably in C?

Comment: Does the PIC microcontroller have a timer?

Comment: Yes it has 2x8bits timer and 1x16bits timer. it is PIC16F819.  If you mean that I can use the timer as interrupt, then the problem is that the PIC has around some hundreds timeslots, some timeslots should receive and some should transmit. so I don't know if it is possible to perform different operations using a single timer triggered interrupt. However it sounds a valid idea, I'll research on that a bit more.

Comment: Could it be possible to use timer triggered interrupt and a counter, This way the counter will determin the operation to be performed. and the timer triggered interrupt will make sure the evenness of timeslots.

Comment: Yes. Like a state machine.

Comment: That will be more effective battery wise as well. and can be done in C. Thanks for the answer Tsukuyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use timer triggered interrupt and a counter, This way the counter will determin the operation to be performed (like a statemachine). and the timer triggered interrupt will make sure the evenness of timeslots.